# How to debug webpacker running twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, rake, webpacker

Rails 5.1.1, ruby 2.4.1, webpacker 2.0, when running system tests through `rake test:system`.

It will be helpful If there is way to see more debug logs, like which file load which modules, etc.

Note that It is happen only when there is no cache, that tests should be. If there is cache, webpacker does not run at all, which is normal.

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-2.0/lib/tasks/installers.rake:1: warning: already initialized constant INSTALLERS
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-2.0/lib/tasks/installers.rake:1: warning: previous definition of INSTALLERS was here
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-2.0/lib/tasks/webpacker/install.rake:1: warning: already initialized constant WEBPACKER_APP_TEMPLATE_PATH
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webpacker-2.0/lib/tasks/webpacker/install.rake:1: warning: previous definition of WEBPACKER_APP_TEMPLATE_PATH was here
Webpacker is installed � �
Using ..../config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
Webpacker is installed � �
Using ..../config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
[Webpacker] Compiling assets �
[Webpacker] Compiling assets �
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that rake task from webpacker is loading the Rakefile again.

https://github.com/rails/webpacker/pull/477/files